# How to tell if dynamically loaded image exists

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, file-exists

I'm dynamically loading images from a different website into an asp.net ListView control like this:

```
<ListView>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <img src='<%# string.Format("http://www.Website.com/Images/{0}", Eval("ImageName")) %>' />
```

Sometimes, the images don't exist and I need to change the src to a static path: src="/whatever/default.png". What is the fastest way I check if the image exists and update the src if it doesn't (any client side possibilities via jQuery)? The ListView is paged and could contain a result set of thousands of records, so I'd only like to check the images that are on the current page to optimize performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jquery you can do it this way:

```
<img src="http://myimages.com/image.jpg" id="imgId" />

$('#imgId').load(function(){
 // ... loaded  
}).error(function(){
 // ... not loaded
 $(this).attr('src','/whatever/default.png');
});
```

Comment: thanks. final solution, which handles partial postbacks inside an update panel: $(document).ready(function () {
    LoadCheck();

    var prmInstance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prmInstance.add_endRequest(function () {
        LoadCheck();
    });
});

function LoadCheck() {
    $('.ThumbnailImage').load(function () {
    }).error(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.website.com/images/default.jpg');
    });
}

Answer (score 0):

I would just try loading the images, and if you get an error, fall back to a default:

```
$('img').error(function()
{
  $(this).attr('src', '/whatever/default.png');
});
```

---

**EDIT:** This solution *might* not work, so I'll supply you with an alternate one. When an image *doesn't* load, it theoretically has a `width` of `0` (assuming you didn't style the `<img>` tags). This code might work:

```
$('img').each(function()
{
  if ($(this).width() == '0px')
  {
    $(this).attr('src', '/whatever/default.png');
  }
});
```