# checking image existance from client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-exists

I am developing one image gallery website, which may have thousands of photos in future. All the images comes from other Website / API or user uploads.

User uploaded images

`<img src="../images/example.jpg" alt="" />`

External Images

`<img src="http://example.com/xyz.jpg" alt="" />`

Let say, image deleted from external website. Is there a way to check photo exists from client side using jQuery / JavaScript etc?

What I think is

i) I hotlink the image from external website

ii) Image deleted from external website, when website first load, jquery will send me the dead link info to server using ajax etc

iii) I will fix the link.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if dynamically loaded image exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502779/how-to-tell-if-dynamically-loaded-image-exists)

Comment: [_error_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/error) [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener), anyone?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I didn't try anything. I am not sure it is possible form client side or not. but it possible from server side that I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("error", "img", function() {
        // do something with $(this) here
    });
});
```

That would detect broken images and allow you to do something about it.

Comment: Archer, script detects if the external website redirect to other `unavailable.jpg` and send image back to my link?

Comment: You can't detect a redirect from an external site - that's not possible.  You could check the filename on load and see if it's `unavailable.jpg`, but if that ever changed your script wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "onerror" event on your external images and create a server side script to handle the error and return a generic "image not found" image while you fix the issue.

Something like ...

```
onerror="this.src='/fiximage.php?q='+this.src;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onerror` event in this case.

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img"),
    img, i = 0;
while (img = imgs[i++]) {
    img.onerror = function() {
        // just an example for error reporting
        Ajax.send("POST /image_error.php", {src:img.src});
        // change img src
        img.src = "images/error.jpg";
    };
}
```